# using expect to loop over output and send to file

Tags: expect

i am trying to use expect to log into an appliance, fetch the config, and write it to a file (i can't use ssh keys, appliance doesn't support it, and the thing actually has two logins).

the problem is when i use this, the data is truncated (i only get the last ~100 lines of the config file):

```
...snip...
match_max 100000
set timeout 150
set output [open "outputfile.txt" "w"]
set config $expect_out(buffer)
puts $output $config
close $output
...snip...
```

so now, per a suggestion i read somewhere, i am trying to use expect to loop over the output, one line at a time, but i can't get the data to output like i could without the loop. here is the code that is not working. the config is ~700 lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
match_max 50000
spawn ssh admin@192.168.1.10
expect "password"
send "password1\r"
expect "user"
send "root\r"
expect "password"
send "password2\r"

set outcome {}
set writeout [open "outputfile.txt" "w"]

expect "device"
exp_send "show running\r"
expect {
        -regexp {.*}{
        set outcome "${outcome}$expect_out(0,string)"
        exp_continue
        }
}
puts $writeout $outcome
close $writeout

expect "device"
send "exit\r"
send "yes\r"
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. let me know if you need any more information.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The loop you provided is equivalent to waiting for timeout (which is default 10seconds as the script doesn't set it).

How long is `show running` printing it's output? It may be worth waiting for some pattern that is displayed after the command finishes (I assume it's `"device"` but may be better to provide more specific terminal condition).

```
exp_send "show running\n"
expect "show running" ;#don't want the command present in captured output
set timeout 60
expect {
   "device" { set raw_outcome $expect_out(0,string) }
   timeout { error "command didn't finish in 60 sec?' }
}
#now the raw_outcome contains everything what was displayed up-to the "device"
#including this string, so filter out the terminal condition:
regexp {(.*)device} $raw_outcome match outcome
puts $writeout $outcome
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The root of this error cause is Expect's multithreading: Expect starts communication with remote system in a separate thread and does not synchronize its output with maint thread's output. So, if you try to write something to main thread's sdtout before a dauther thread finished, you likely meet deadlock in Expect.